# binary search for a solution in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, return-value, binary-search

I tried to write a binary search program to find the maximum x that satisfies

```
x**2+(n-x-small)-(x-small)*(x-small-1)/2 <= maxSum
```

Since I don't know how to solve the equation directly. Only x is the unknown. `lst` contains a range of possible integer values

Somehow the code below did not give any return value, although it can print at each condition. I have been stuck with the following code for hours and not sure what went wrong.

```
def binarySearch(self, lst, n, small, maxSum):
        m=len(lst)
        if m==1: 
            x=lst[0]
            a=x**2+(n-x-small)-(x-small)*(x-small-1)/2
            if a<=maxSum:
                return x
            else:
                return x-1
        else:
            j=m//2
            x=lst[j]
            a=x**2+(n-x-small)-(x-small)*(x-small-1)/2
            if a==maxSum:
                return x
            elif a > maxSum:
                self.binarySearch(lst[:j], n, small, maxSum)
            elif a < maxSum:
                self.binarySearch(lst[j:], n, small, maxSum)
```

Comment: How are you calling this? I'm not convinced binary search is an appropriate tool for solving this problem--are you sure the outcome of each comparison is orderable? Sample input would be helpful, along with a list of assumptions for the possible values of `small`, `n` and `lst`. Also, there's virtually no point to binary searching if you use slices on the list. As soon as you slice the list, your complexity is linear, at which point you might as well write a linear algorithm and skip pretending you have a logarithmic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing with recursion is that you have to **return** the recursion function.

You didn't do that at the end of the elif statements, that's why it did the calculation but lost the answer on the way back from the recursion. :)

just add 2 returns before your calling the recurstion like below:

```
def binarySearch(self, lst, n, small, maxSum):
m = len(lst)
if m == 1:
    x = lst[0]
    a = x ** 2 + (n - x - small) - (x - small) * (x - small - 1) / 2
    if a <= maxSum:
        return x
    else:
        return x - 1
else:
    j = m // 2
    x = lst[j]
    a = x ** 2 + (n - x - small) - (x - small) * (x - small - 1) / 2
    if a == maxSum:
        return x
    elif a > maxSum:
        return binarySearch(lst[:j], n, small, maxSum)
    elif a < maxSum:
        return binarySearch(lst[(j + 1):], n, small, maxSum)
```

elif a > maxSum:

**return** binarySearch(lst[:j], n, small, maxSum)

elif a < maxSum:

**return** binarySearch(lst[(j + 1):], n, small, maxSum)

Comment: I see! That is my mistake. Thanks so much!

Comment: Your welcome.

I see that your kinda new on stack overflow, if it helped you solve your problem can you please thumb up my answer ?

Comment: Sure. Since I am really new, it seems my thumb up did not show, but hopefully it was recorded.